# Integrating Power pdf to get energy pdf?

Tags: statistics, probability

I'm trying to work out how to solve what seems like a simple problem, but I can't convince myself of the correct method.

I have time-series data that represents the pdf of a Power output (P), varying over time, also the cdf and quantile functions - f(P,t), F(P,t) and q(p,t). I need to find the pdf, cdf and quantile function for the Energy in a given time interval [t1,t2] from this data - say e(), E(), and qe().

Clearly energy is the integral of the power over [t1,t2], but how do I best calculate e, E and qe ?

My best guess is that since q(p,t) is a power, I should generate qe by integrating q over the time interval, and then calculate the other distributions from that.

Is it as simple as that, or do I need to get to grips with stochastic calculus ?

**Additional details for clarification**

The data we're getting is a time-series of 'black-box' forecasts for f(P), F(P),q(P) for each time t, where P is the instantaneous power and there will be around 100 forecasts for the interval I'd like to get the e(P) for. By 'Black-box' I mean that there will be a function I can call to evaluate f,F,q for P, but I don't know the underlying distribution.

The black-box functions are almost certainly interpolating output data from the model that produces the power forecasts, but we don't have access to that. I would guess that it **won't** be anything straightforward, since it comes from a chain of non-linear transformations. It's actually wind farm production forecasts: the wind speeds may be normally distributed, but multiple terrain and turbine transformations will change that.

**Further clarification**
(I've edited the original text to remove confusing variable names in the energy distribution functions.)

The forecasts will be provided as follows:

The interval [t1,t2] that we need e, E and qe for is sub-divided into 100 (say) sub-intervals k=1...100. For each k we are given a distinct f(P), call them f_k(P). We need to calculate the energy distributions for the interval from this set of f_k(P).

Comment: What is the distribution of P? (Normal, log-normal, something else?) Are you given power at an instant in time or average power over some time interval? Is P given by a formula only or is it derived from recorded measurements? Thanks for any additional info.

Comment: @RobertDodier I've added some further details to help clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. When you say there are 100 forecasts, do you mean there is one time series over 100 subintervals, k = 1, ..., 100, and a different f(P, t) for each k? Or do you mean that there are 100 time series?

Comment: @RobertDodier I've added more clarification..I think :-) I believe we will get a time-series of forecasts - 100 individual pdfs, one for each k in the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. From what I can tell, you don't have enough information to solve this problem properly. Specifically, you need to have some estimate of the dependence of power from one time step to the next. The longer the time step, the less the dependence; if the steps are long enough, power might be approximately independent from one step to the next, which would be good news because that would simplify the analysis quite a bit. So, how long are the time steps? An hour? A minute? A day?

If the time steps are long enough to be independent, the distribution of energy is the distribution of 100 variables, which will be very nearly normally distributed by the central limit theorem. It's easy to work out the mean and variance of the total energy in this case.

Otherwise, the distribution will be some more complicated result. My guess is that the variance as estimated by the independent-steps approach will be too big -- the actual variance would be somewhat less, I believe.

From what you say, you don't have any information about temporal dependence. Maybe you can find or derive from some other source or sources an estimate the autocorrelation function -- I wouldn't be surprised if that question has already been studied for wind power. I also wouldn't be surprised if a general version of this problem has already been studied -- perhaps you can search for something like "distribution of a sum of autocorrelated variables." You might get some interest in that question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This has helped me to realise that the problem as I've stated it can't be what is actually going on. There's a misunderstanding somewhere about what these forecast f(P) actually are - not sure at which end :-) Since it's wind that driving this, there **must** be a correlation between each sub-interval - that's the point of the forecast. Also, the subintervals are minutes apart, so there are physical limits on how much the power can change. Thanks for helping me understand this - I'll do some more googling, since we can't be the first people to need to look at this.

Comment: Jack, I'll be interested to know what you find out.